# Please explain the output for bitfield 1

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    struct value
     { 
      int bit1:1;
      int bit2:4;
      int bit3:4;
     }
   bit ={1,2,2};
   printf("%d %d %d \n",bit.bit1,bit.bit2,bit.bit3);

   return 0;
}
```

Output : -1 2 2

Hi ,I am not able to understand structure bitfields.How the negative value is coming .

Comment: Please Explain the value for output for bit.bit1 .Why it is negative value.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hi ,I am not able to understand structure bitfields.How the negative value is coming .

Comment: Put that in the question, then, instead of a comment!

Comment: You should include the output you get and the output you expect in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int bits:2;
```

can store 00(0), 01(1), 10(-2), 11(-1) <sup>*Assuming 2s complement system for signed</sup>

```
unsigned int bits:2;
```

can store 00(0), 01(1), 10(2), 11(3)

Bit representation of both types that can be represented is same but the interpretation is different.

You are using `:1`, so it can store 0 or -1, so the negative output. You are trying to store 1, which can not be represented by `int :1`, so the output is surprising. Takeaway is, don't do that.

**Conclusion** Almost always use `unsigned` for bitfield members. Rewrite the structure as:

```
struct value
{ 
  unsigned int bit1:1;
  unsigned int bit2:4;
  unsigned int bit3:4;
};
```

Comment: It can store 0 or -1, no 1.

Comment: @Mohit : can you please explain the working of bitfields.I referred geeksforgeeks.org too.

Comment: @shaina this is a broad topic. I would suggest a C book or some [basic tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm) to grasp a better hand.

Answer (score 2):

`bit1` in the structure is of type `int`. when you don't specify `unsigned` before int like `unsigned int` it will be treated as `signed`integer! and for bit1 you have mentioned size as 1 bit, that means `bit1` can have only 2 values! 0 and 1. when you assigned `bit1` with 1, it will print -1 as type is `int`. as we know, for `int` variables if the MSB bit it set then it is a negative number!
`bit2` and `bit3` are of size 4 bits, So its value can be ranged from 0 till 15 (0b1111).

To know more about bit fields, please check this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm